# ASP Net Core Angular - Default Project with bootstrap 4 instead of 3 (SideMenu)

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a website with Angular6 where there is a vertical navbar when viewed on a large screen and a top navbar with a dropdown on mobile. With Bootstrap 4. I have found multiple examples online but they all seems overly complicated or build without the nav template.

The example project from ASP.Net Core with Angular have a navbar like I want but it is written with Bootstrap3. I have tried to convert it without success and this is where I ask for your help!

Original Code with Bootstrap 3. If you have dotnet core installed, you can use `dotnet new angular -o my-new-app` to create the project.

HTML

```
<div class='main-nav'>
<div class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
    <div class='navbar-header'>
        <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse' [attr.aria-expanded]='isExpanded' (click)='toggle()'>
            <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
        </button>
        <a class='navbar-brand' [routerLink]='["/"]'>my_new_app</a>
    </div>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' [ngClass]='{ "in": isExpanded }'>
        <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
            <li [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]' [routerLinkActiveOptions]='{ exact: true }'>
                <a [routerLink]='["/"]' (click)='collapse()'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]'>
                <a [routerLink]='["/counter"]' (click)='collapse()'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> Counter
                </a>
            </li>
            <li [routerLinkActive]='["link-active"]'>
                <a [routerLink]='["/fetch-data"]' (click)='collapse()'>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
li .glyphicon {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/* Highlighting rules for nav menu items */
li.link-active a,
li.link-active a:hover,
li.link-active a:focus {
    background-color: #4189C7;
    color: white;
}

/* Keep the nav menu independent of scrolling and on top of other items */
.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* On small screens, convert the nav menu to a vertical sidebar */
    .main-nav {
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(25% - 20px);
    }
    .navbar {
        border-radius: 0px;
        border-width: 0px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid #444;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .navbar ul {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar li {
        float: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin: 6px;
    }
    .navbar li a {
        padding: 10px 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
    .navbar a {
        /* If a menu item's text is too long, truncate it */
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

And here is my attempt to convert it. I used the Bootstrap 4 documentation for the template

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="nav flex-column">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[image: Side by side instead of new line]

The problem is that the title and the nav are on the same line instead of having then on separate line. How could I achieve that?

(The mobile view doesn't seem to work either, but I haven't tried yet. I am trying to make the desktop view work first)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I didn't search long enough. I found the solution here: http://www.codingflow.net/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-2-1-with-angular-6-part-2-upgrading-to-bootstrap-4/

One of the key changes was this in the css

```
.flex-column {
  width: 100%;
}
```